# How to add multiple color snow-balls in javascript & canvas animation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have used ***fillstyle*** in javascript and i want multiple color snowballs in it, how can i use it? I have tried using multiple functions and also multiple canvas but not able to do it, please help

Answer (score 2):

Hard to tell without code but I will guess that you are not using ctx.beginPath() each time you want to draw a different colour.

```js
var ctx = can.getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "red";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(Math.random()*100+10,Math.random()*100+10,10,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx.fill();

ctx.fillStyle = "green";
ctx.beginPath();  // start a new path
ctx.arc(Math.random()*100+10,Math.random()*100+10,10,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx.fill();
ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
ctx.beginPath(); // start a new path
ctx.arc(Math.random()*100+10,Math.random()*100+10,10,0,Math.PI*2);
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="can"></canvas>
```